# Tokenizing very large text datasets (cannot fit in RAM/GPU Memory) with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tokenize, data-preprocessing

How do we tokenize very large text datasets that don't fit into memory in Tensorflow? For image datasets, there is the ImageDataGenerator that loads the data per batch to the model, and preprocesses the data. However for text datasets, tokenization is performed before training the model. Can the dataset be split into batches for the tokenizer or is there a Tensorflow batch tokenizer function that already exist? Can this be done without having to import external libraries?

I know that there are external libraries that does this. For example from, https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need to define your own data processing pipeline using the [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data) module. Based on this module you can define an own/customized [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset). Those datasets support a lot of features like parsing of records into a specific format (using the [map function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map)) or [batching](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch).

Here is a complete example of how you could use the tf.data module for building your own pipeline: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I read through the link and you are right, it could be that the only way is to build a custom processing function or pipeline, or use an external library. Specifically for text tokenization, the entirety of the data is usually preloaded and tokenized in one shot. There isn't a Tokenizer.add_tokens() function that facilitates batchwise processing, so even if we were to load the data in batches I don't see how we can tokenize the data using the individual batches, without importing an external library or writing a custom tokenizer

Comment: Ohh yes, I got your point. If I got the Tensorflow Docs correctly, the tf.text Tokenizers are compatible with tf.data.Datasets to feed in data in batches: https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/tokenizers#tf_data 

But you are right, also for this approach, you need to define some kind of custom pipeline.